# Trailing whitespace in zsh commands

Tags: bash, zsh

I am writing a zsh script that captures a hostname from file `README` and ensures that it exists on the network by pinging it. The following is my code:

```
HOSTNAME=$(cat README 2>/dev/null | grep -oP "^Host(name)*:[\s]+\K(.*)")
ping -w 5 -c 1 $HOSTNAME >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    # error
else
    # all good
fi
```

I noticed that if the line that contains the hostname in `README` has a trailing space, `ping` doesn't work. For example, the line could look like the following where I represent white space with an `_` character.

```
Hostname:____bobscomputer_
```

Does zsh not get rid of extra whitespace in its commands like bash does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) of unquoted variables, which [Bash does implicitly but Zsh doesn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26661/117037). For example:

```
$ cat test.sh
var="foo bar"
printf '%s\n' $var
$ bash test.sh
foo
bar
$ zsh test.sh
foo bar
```

If you wanted to do word splitting in Zsh, use `$=var`.

BTW, here's an awk command that's simpler and avoids the problem (assuming hostnames can't contain whitespace):

```
HOSTNAME=$(awk '/^Host(name)?:/ {print $2}' README)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `HOSTNAME` has some whitespace on the tail end. One way to fix this is to [strip leading/trailing whitespace from a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259691/trimming-whitespace-from-the-ends-of-a-string-in-zsh).

In this case, you could do so by adding a line above the `ping` command, shown below:

**Before**

```sh
# Original line
ping -w 5 -c 1 $HOSTNAME >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**After**

```sh
# Strip leading/trailing whitespace from $HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME=${(MS)HOSTNAME##[[:graph:]]*[[:graph:]]}

# Original line
ping -w 5 -c 1 $HOSTNAME >/dev/null 2>&1
```