# Trimming whitespace from the ends of a string in Zsh

Tags: string, zsh, whitespace, glob, parameter-expansion

How does one remove any and all whitespace from the ends of a string in Zsh without spawning another process?

After looking at [the documentation for expansion in Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) (namely sections [14.3 Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-1) and [14.8.1 Glob Operators](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators))—also viewable via `$ man zshexpn`—I've written the following code:

```
${${var##[:space:]##}%%[:space:]##}
```

But Zsh doesn't seem to recognize the `[:space:]` glob operator. As per my understanding of the following statement in the documentation, it *should*:

> In the expansions discussed below that require a pattern, the form of the pattern is the same as that used for filename generation; see Filename Generation. Note that these patterns, along with the replacement text of any substitutions, are themselves subject to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

Is this a bug in Zsh or am I overlooking something?

For now, I'm just using `${${var## ##}%% ##}` which at least substitutes any and all space characters at the ends.

I'm using Zsh 5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the `zsh` Glob Operator documentation:

> Note that the square brackets are additional to those enclosing the whole set of characters, so to test for a single alphanumeric character you need `‘[[:alnum:]]’`.

So just using `[:space:]` instead of `[[:space:]]` is your problem.

---

#### Aside:

There are a few ways to say "Match multiple copies of the previous thing" in `zsh` glob patterns. One, which you used, requires the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option to be turned on, is to use `x##`, which *matches one or more occurrences of the pattern x* (There's also `x#`, which *matches zero or more occurrences of the pattern x*). Another, which needs the `KSH_GLOB` option to work, is `+(x)`, which also matches one or more occurrences of `x` (And `*(x)` matches 0 or more.) This style has the advantage of working with `ksh` and `bash` (The latter needs the `extglob` option enabled) and thus might be more familiar to someone coming from another shell.

So:

```sh
$ foo=$(printf " \t bar baz \t ") # Spaces and tabs before and after
$ printf ">%s<\n" "$foo"                               
>    bar baz     <
$ printf ">%s<\n" "${${foo##[[:space:]]##}%%[[:space:]]##}"
>bar baz<
$ setopt KSH_GLOB                                            
$ printf ">%s<\n" "${${foo##+([[:space:]])}%%+([[:space:]])}"
>bar baz<
```

removes all the leading and trailing whitespace characters like you want.

Also note this nesting of expansions is `zsh`-specific. It won't work in other shells, where the two deletions will require multiple steps.

Answer (score 4):

You're really close.

1. You need to modify your [POSIX Basic Regular Expression](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) character class syntax a bit
2. You can simplify the expression by using the `(MS)` (matching substring) [parameter expansion flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
${(MS)var##[[:graph:]]*[[:graph:]]}
```

## Solution

In the example below, the parameter we will strip leading/trailing whitespace from has the identifier `var`. Substitute this as necessary in your own code.

```sh
typeset var=$'\n\t   abc   def   \n\t'
```

**Printing a parameter stripped of any leading/trailing whitespace:**

```sh
print -n -- ${(MS)var##[[:graph:]]*[[:graph:]]}
```

**Output**: `abc def`

Answer (score -2):

```sh
$ foo=" \n \t  ab dd ef   \n"

$ print $foo | xargs
ab dd ef
```

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/trim_string_bash/

Comment: This is in the very first sentence of my post: “without spawning another process.”

Comment: Excuse me please. I'm sorry. But this solution is good for others which comes from goole and for them is not “without spawning another process.”  importent.

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.