# Use values in input csv to search a second csv and return values

Tags: function, zsh, ifs

I have an input csv with 3 columns and many rows.  For each row, I want to use the string in each column to sequentially search a second csv.  When a match is found I want to return columns from the row where the match occurred.  My code works for the most part, but for some reason refuses to return the output for the 3rd column of each row before moving to the next.  I'm stumped.  TYIA!

Input.csv:
A1,A2,A3
B1,B2,B3

Search.csv:
A1,Name2,C2,UniqueID1,C2,C3,C4
A3,Name2,C2,UniqueID2,C2,C3,C4
A2,Name4,C2,UniqueID3,C2,C3,C4
B2,Name4,C2,UniqueID4,C2,C3,C4
B3,Name3,C2,UniqueID5,C2,C3,C4
B1,Name2,C2,UniqueID6,C2,C3,C4

```
Desired Output:  
/Name2/UniqueID1/  
/Name4/UniqueID3/  
/Name2/UniqueID2/  
/Name2/UniqueID6/  
/Name4/UniqueID4/  
/Name3/UniqueID5/  

Current Output:  
/Name2/UniqueID1/  
/Name4/UniqueID3/  
/Name2/UniqueID6/  
/Name4/UniqueID4/
```

```
#!/bin/zsh

# Function to process CSV files
process_csv() {
    local input_file="$1"
    local search_column="$2"
    local search_file="$3"
    local output_column1="$4"
    local output_column2="$5"

    # Loop through the input CSV file
    while IFS= read -r input_line || [[ -n "$input_line" ]]; do
        # Extract values from input CSV using IFS as a separator
        IFS=',' read -r -A input_values <<< "$input_line"
        input_var1="${input_values[1]}"  # Adjust column index as needed
        input_var2="${input_values[2]}"  # Adjust column index as needed
        input_var3="${input_values[3]}"  # Adjust column index as needed

        # Initialize a variable to store the result for the current row
        row_result=""

        # Search for each input variable sequentially
        search_for_input_var "$input_var1" "$search_file" "$search_column" "$output_column1" "$output_column2" row_result
        search_for_input_var "$input_var2" "$search_file" "$search_column" "$output_column1" "$output_column2" row_result
        search_for_input_var "$input_var3" "$search_file" "$search_column" "$output_column1" "$output_column2" row_result

        # Output the concatenated result for the current row
        #echo "Matches found for '$input_var1', '$input_var2', '$input_var3': $row_result"
    done < "$input_file"
}

# Function to search for an input variable in the search CSV file
search_for_input_var() {
    local input_var="$1"
    local search_file="$2"
    local search_column="$3"
    local output_column1="$4"
    local output_column2="$5"
    local result_var="$6"  # Result variable passed by name

    # Reset the result for the current input variable
    result_var=""

    # Loop through the search CSV file
    while IFS= read -r search_line; do
        # Extract values from search CSV using IFS as a separator
        IFS=',' read -r -A search_values <<< "$search_line"
        search_var="${search_values[$search_column]}"  # Adjust column index as needed

        # Check if the current input value matches the search value
        if [ "$input_var" = "$search_var" ]; then
            # Concatenate desired columns with '/' separator 
            result="/${search_values[$output_column1]}/${search_values[$output_column2]}/"
            echo $result
            if [ -n "$result_var" ]; then
                result_var="${result_var}/$result"
            else
                result_var="$result"
            fi
            break  # Stop searching the search CSV once a match is found
        fi
    done < "$search_file"
}

# Usage: ./process_csv.sh Input.csv 1 Search.csv 2 4

input_csv="$1"
search_column="$2"
search_csv="$3"
output_column1="$4"
output_column2="$5"

process_csv "$input_csv" "$search_column" "$search_csv" "$output_column1" "$output_column2"
```

Comment: Are you sure that your CSVs can be processed without a parser?

Comment: Yes.  I made them myself and the only non-alphabetical values that the cells contain are an occasional `_`.  No spaces, `,`, or `"` are present in cell values.

Comment: Check the line terminations of your input files.  When I ran your code with the input files, I got the desired result with six lines. When I changed the input.csv file to have DOS-style CRLF endings (I'm on a Mac), the output had four lines.

Comment: Some info on checking line endings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/how-to-find-out-line-endings-in-a-text-file

Comment: Hi Gairfowl.  What terminators should the CSV files have?  My input.csv has `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` and my search.csv has `CSV text
- , ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: SHEESH!  This was the problem!  Thanks so much @Gairfowl.   For anyone else: I am working on a Mac and I opened the csv files in BBEdit and saved a new copy using Line Breaks for Unix (LF); it's a drop-down option.  The problem likely arose because I made my csv files in excel, so they had CRLF line terminators.  You can determine the line terminators of your file by typing `file -k somefile.csv`.  Visit the thread Gairfowl mentioned above for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments, the input csv files do not have line terminations that match the platform, so the last value ends up with some extraneous whitespace at the end. One option is to trim whitespace from the values after parsing the `csv' string:

```bash
    IFS=',' read -r -A input_values <<< "$input_line"
    input_values=(${(MS)input_values##[[:graph:]]*[[:graph:]]})
```

This particular substitution (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68288735)) is a little overdone - it will trim all leading and trailing whitespace from all of the values in the `input_values` array. But that might help with other ways that Excel likes to confuse things when creating csv files.

You could remove just the CR character being added here with this, after reading `input_line`:

```bash
    input_line=${input_line%$'\r'}
```

Comment: Hi @Gairfowl, my code does not process the final row of `Input.csv`.  I can expand `Input.csv` to have many more rows, but it never processes the last row.  No errors are thrown; it simply doesn't loop the last row.  I tried both methods of converting the line terminations and the issue persists, so I don't think it's related to line terminations...?  Any ideas why this might be the case?  TYIA

Comment: I found it.  During the loop through csv I added ` || [[ -n "$input_line" ]]; do` so that the complete line now reads `while IFS= read -r input_line || [[ -n "$input_line" ]]; do`  I will adjust it in my question if it allows me to edit as this was not the  purpose of the question and others will have the issue if trying to adapt the code.

Answer (score 2):

Processing text with the shell isn't considered a good practice.

The best standard tool for this kind of task would be `awk`:

```bash
LANG=C awk -F',' -v OFS='/' -v search_column="1" -v output_columns="2 4" '
    BEGIN {
        outColsCount = split(output_columns, outColsArr, " ")
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        sub(/^\357\273\277/,"")    # strip BOM
    }
    {
        sub("\r$","")              # strip CR(LF)
    }
    FNR == NR {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
            searchDB[$i]
        next
    }
    $search_column in searchDB {
        for ( i = 1; i <= outColsCount; i++ )
            printf("%s", OFS $outColsArr[i])
        print ""
    }
' Input.csv Search.csv
```

```
/Name2/UniqueID2
/Name4/UniqueID3
/Name4/UniqueID4
/Name3/UniqueID5
/Name2/UniqueID6
```

**notes:**

- `FNR == NR` is only true for the first input file. In the corresponding block of code we fill an array using the fields of `Input.csv` as keys.
- `$search_column in searchDB` is true when we got a match, so we print the requested columns.

---

Making it a function:

```bash
process_csv() {                       
    local input_file="$1"
    local search_column="$2"
    local search_file="$3"
    local -a output_columns
    output_columns=( "${@:4}" )

    LANG=C awk -F',' -v OFS='/' \
        -v search_column="$search_column" \
        -v output_columns="${output_columns[*]}" \
        '
            BEGIN {
                outColsCount = split(output_columns, outColsArr, " ")
            }
            FNR == 1 {
                sub(/^\357\273\277/,"")    # strip BOM
            }
            {
                sub("\r$","")              # strip CR(LF)
            }
            FNR == NR {
                for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
                    searchDB[$i]
                next
            }
            $search_column in searchDB {
                for ( i = 1; i <= outColsCount; i++ )
                    printf("%s", OFS $outColsArr[i])
                print ""
            }
        ' \
        "$input_file" "$search_file"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fravadona, I will give this a try once I get to a computer later this morning.

Comment: @JVGen I added the auto-removal of CRLF in the `awk` program

Comment: Hi @Fravadona, in your function where you have `... awk code ...`, am I meant to insert your awk code from the first code block, starting with `BEGIN` through to the last `}`?  I'm not experienced with `awk`

Comment: @JVGen that's right, I did it for you

Comment: If I run the awk code alone I get an error: `awk: towc: multibyte conversion failure`.  I'm guessing this is because I already converted the line terminators in a previous step?

Comment: @JVGen If the CSV was generated with Excel then you might have a BOM at the start that needs to be removed; also, imposing LANG=C might be required. It's fixed now